# How can i fix Bad JNI version returned from JNI_OnLoad error on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

When I extract the app as apk and test it on a real Android device, it crashes, but when I run it as debug it works fine. The cause of the error is pub.dev --> video_editor library. I got this error output from Firebase:

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
Bad JNI version returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.projectName--b7nYjATxtDAUxnuC_rpnQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmobileffmpeg.so": 0
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 (Runtime.java:1016)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:1657)
com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config.<clinit> (Config.java:146)
com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config.nativeFFprobeExecute (Config.java)
com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.FFprobe.execute (FFprobe.java)
com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.FFprobe.getMediaInformationFromCommandArguments (FFprobe.java)
com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.FFprobe.getMediaInformation (FFprobe.java:48)
com.arthenica.flutter.ffmpeg.FlutterFFmpegGetMediaInformationAsyncTask.doInBackground (FlutterFFmpegGetMediaInformationAsyncTask.java:21)
com.arthenica.flutter.ffmpeg.FlutterFFmpegGetMediaInformationAsyncTask.doInBackground (FlutterFFmpegGetMediaInformationAsyncTask.java:2)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:333)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling ProGuard on releases older than v0.2.4 causes linking errors. Please add the following rule inside your proguard-rules.pro file to preserve necessary method names and prevent linking errors.

```
-keep class com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config {
  native <methods>;
  void log(int, byte[]);
  void statistics(int, float, float, long , int, double, double);
 }
```

and also make sure that mavenCentral() is defined as a repository in your build.gradle and it is listed before jcenter().

Refer from flutter ffmpeg documentation https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg